# How can I make an android app for a website I do not own?

Tags: php, android, mysql, feed

So, here I am asking for some ideas on how to make an android app for a website I do not own. 
So, I just started android app developing, I am a newbie at this :3. This website I am talking about, I do not own it, it neither has a RSS feed nor api. Its a job advertising website, I guess each jod advertisement is a post, the language is not English. I want to make a android app for this website, to display the advertisements. Once the advertisement have been watched, I want it to be also available to watch later without an internet connection. Can you please give me some idea on how to make this app? I can use HTML, PHP and mysql too (to fetch data from the website?)

Thank you all in advance. Sorry for being noob >.<

Comment: Write a site scrapper for this website and server this data to the android device with an API

Comment: Wow, please DONT do this

Comment: Go get your own website first, then create your own content, then make that available offline in an android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unexperienced with android programming, but familiar with HTML and PHP, I would suggest you to get your personal webspace and write a php-script that parses the html pages of the foreign website, display it nicely and refer the users of you app to your personal webspace.

Even if a website has no rss feed and no API, there is (almost) always a way to find a regular expression that can extract the useful information.

The even better solution would be to ask the websites owner to offer you an API. This way you don't have a broken app every time the websites owner decides to changes the logic/layout of his site. And he will not sue you, if your server creates mass of traffic on his server...